# What defines a marker cookie?

Tags: http, cookies, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Trying to google `marker cookie` just makes you hungry, so I decided to come here instead.

I've seen it pop up in statements like this:

> Local/session storage won't work across domains, use a marker cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A marker cookie is a cookie that contains a unique marker (identifier, if you will) to the hash of all session variables on the server. As with most cookies, they're typically encrypted.

Essentially, a marker cookie is the encrypted key to access your session variables.

Comment: Super - Do you know how to make one by chance?

Comment: @Ole Typically it'll literally be the key to the hash table. The hash's values would then contain whatever you'd normally be storing locally.

Comment: OK now I'm confused again :) - Also it says local sessions wont work across domains - use a marker cookie ... and the context is a OpenID Connect / OAuth type of context - so I'm presuming that the cookie can be identified to both the client application and the OpenID Connect Provider / OAuth Authorization Server which are / could be on separate domains ...

Comment: @Ole Not sure why any cookies would need to be sent to the OAuth provider/server. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: This is the article containing the statement: https://auth0.com/blog/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/             Perhaps it's just a miss statement, since OpenID Connect providers / OAuth Authorization Servers should only need to identify you when you are revisiting their site.

Comment: I think your answer is correct - the statement is a bit misleading.  It makes it sound as if the cookie is supposed to work across domains, but it's only purposes (If I'm reasoning about this right) is to identify you to the OpenID Connect / OAuth Authorization Server where you currently have a session.

Comment: Yeah, across domains = across different subdomains here (I think)